# Escaping text for saving in Postgres

Tags: javascript, regex, postgresql

I am trying to escape user-generated input text, so save it in Postgres. My escape function is below:

```
module.exports = str => {
  if (!str) return str;

  const specials = [
    '[',
    ']',
    '(',
    ')',
    '/',
    '{',
    '}',
    '(',
    ')',
    '*',
    '+',
    '?',
    '\\',
    '^',
    '$',
    '|',
    "'"
  ];
  const regex = RegExp('[' + specials.join('\\') + ']', 'g');

  return str.replace(regex, "'$&");
};
```

It works fine for many symbols, including `'`, yet somehow it does not work for `(` and `)` - I get an error from Postgres - `syntax error at or near \"(\"`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the PostgreSQL code that throws the exception?

Comment: how does one prevent people from editing their questions?

Comment: Why do you even need to escape something? PostgreSQL can store about anything you throw at it?

Comment: Why do you try to escape the input? If you're trying to avoid SQL injection, use the standard functions in your programming language to safely handle your data. Reinventing the wheel usually results in a square wheel...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not curate the query by yourself, since this is an obvious [attack vector for SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Escaping). You should not escape your queries, but maybe use [parameterized queries](https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/node-postgres-parameterized-query-954).

The optimal and SQL injection-proof code might look something like this in the end:

```
const sql = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE salary > $1 AND id = $2";
const values = [55000, 1];
client.query(sql, values);
```

Comment: is there `==` in SQL, or you have a typo in your query?